# Drive time analysis with ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, network-analyst, arcgis-9.1

What is the most common SETTING for the [Layer Properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000056000000.htm) when creating time-travel polygons?

I am in the process of creating 4, 5, 6 minute polygons using Network Analyst.  Every time I generate these polygons they have different shapes.

I would like to be consistent from one year to another based on the number of streets that are being added to our Center Line Street Network.

Using ArcInfo – 9.1 SP #1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at how Esri have designed their model that sits behind their service area task (drive time polygons).

Info about the model can be seen [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/GP_service_example_Drive_time_polygons/002v0000001p000000/), although to get more information, you can download the model from your ArcGIS Desktop installation media (under ArcTutor folder) and open it up to pick out the specific settings.